# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Acess c++ dll

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, import

I converted .cpp file into .dll file and use this .dll file in my vb.net project. Acess c++ dll in my vb.net projevct, I got this error, " Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." Can get any help here ?
Here is my vb.net code:

```
Public NotInheritable Class myTestDLL
    <DllImport("encryption.dll", EntryPoint:="conv16to64", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Public Shared Sub conv16to64(ByVal c As String, ByRef s As String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is my c++ function code:

```
 extern "C"{
_declspec(dllexport) void conv16to64(char s[], char b[])
{
    int i,j;
    char t[65],c[65];

    for (i=0; i<=16; i++)
        c[i] = s[i];

    for (i=1; i<=64; i++)
        t[i] = 0;

    for (i=0; i<=15; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            j = 0;
        else if (i == 1)
            j = 4;
        else if (i == 2)
            j = 8;
        else if (i == 3)
            j = 12;
        else if (i == 4)
            j = 16;
        else if (i == 5)
            j = 20;
        else if (i == 6)
            j = 24;
        else if (i == 7)
            j = 28;
        else if (i == 8)
            j = 32;
        else if (i == 9)
            j = 36;
        else if (i == 10)
            j = 40;
        else if (i == 11)
            j = 44;
        else if (i == 12)
            j = 48;
        else if (i == 13)
            j = 52;
        else if (i == 14)
            j = 56;
        else if (i == 15)
            j = 60;

        switch (c[i]) {
        case '0': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case '1': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case '2': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case '3': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case '4': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case '5': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case '6': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case '7': t[j+1] = 0; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case '8': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case '9': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case 'A': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case 'B': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 0;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case 'C': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case 'D': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 0; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        case 'E': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 0;
            break;
        case 'F': t[j+1] = 1; t[j+2] = 1;
            t[j+3] = 1; t[j+4] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i=1; i<=64; i++)
        b[i] = t[i];
}
```

Comment: So it couldn't be a bug in your C++ code that you didn't show us, right?

Comment: Also, those are just definitions and don't tell us anything.  How about posting how you're calling these functions, whether those character arrays are valid, whether the DLL code processes these arrays correctly etc.

Comment: Instead of a big if/else chain, can't you just use `j = i * 4;`?

Answer (score 1):

Going over your code there are a few issues, the biggest two are:

You are attempting to retrieve a string back across the native domain without specifying type.

And as pointed out above, you are trying to read in 16 characters, but are referencing them as 17 (are you considering the null char?).

Ideally, in situations like this, you want to do two of the following things with C:
Create your string buffers 1 element larger than your source expectation.
Initialize your buffers to null.

By doing this, you create a more manageable data handler, and are not only less error prone, but also able to recover from user error much easier (and will be buffer resistant).

First to address the first issue I stated, you have the following:

```
Public NotInheritable Class myTestDLL
    <DllImport("encryption.dll", EntryPoint:="conv16to64", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Public Shared Sub conv16to64(ByVal c As String, ByRef s As String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Should actually be:

```
Public NotInheritable Class myTestDLL
    <DllImport("encryption.dll", EntryPoint:="conv16to64", _
        CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, _
        CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Public Shared Sub conv16to64(ByVal c As String, _
        ByVal s As IntPtr)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Under normal string handling situations, your method is perfectly fine.  However, if you are using characters as an array, they are not actually a string, and should not be treated as one across domain.  It becomes too messy.  Handle it as a pointer, and and translate it locally. This allows you to manage error situations on the .net side of things, rather than letting .net handle it for you.  If you have control over the native function (and I have more information about that below), you can make it more stable so that you don't need to worry about managing it on the .net side.

This is far easier to manage the data you are passing in and out.  You assign a 65byte array and after the return of your function, Marshal the Byte Array to a String.

As was pointed out, you are doing a blind pass of variables.  The new Microsoft standard for this type of operation would actually be:

```
extern "C"{
_declspec(dllexport) void conv16to64(const char* s, size_t inSize, char* b, size_t& outSize)
{ ...
```

Or:

```
extern "C"{
_declspec(dllexport) void conv16to64(const char* s, size_t inSize, char* b, size_t* pOutSize)
{ ...
```

The significance here is that you want to be able to validate your size.  The call to these from VB would look like:

```
    <DllImport("encryption.dll", EntryPoint:="conv16to64", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Public Shared Sub conv16to64(ByVal c As IntPtr, ByVal inSize as int64, ByVal s As IntPtr, ByRef outSize as int64)
    End Sub
```

I personally create a wrapper function for my imports in .net, it works for better development practices, and simplifies a lot of logic that tends to be added when dealing with native imports.  Here you will notice I only wrap the function I expose.  Which is actually because it is the one that requires custom logic.  However, if I were to expose the ZeroMemory function, I might create a wrapper call.  That way I could handle exceptions in the call (e.g. if there were alternate logic that could be used if the library was unavailable, or to allow for changes in libraries without causing shifts in my exposed code).

Using your example, I would actually have the following for my VB class

```
Public NotInheritable Class myTestDLL
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="RtlZeroMemory")>
    Private Shared Sub ZeroMemory(ByVal dst As IntPtr, length As Integer)
    End Sub

    <DllImport("encryption.dll", EntryPoint:="conv16to64", _
        CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, _
        CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
    Private Shared Sub conv16to64(ByVal c As String, _
        ByVal s As IntPtr)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function Convert16to64( _
        ByVal charTest As String) As String

        Dim incoming As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(65)
        Dim retVal As String = ""
        Try
            ZeroMemory(incoming, 65)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Add some exception handling here '
        End Try

        Try
            conv16to64(charTest, incoming)
            retVal = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(incoming)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(incoming)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Add some exception handling here '
        End Try
        Return retVal
    End Function
End Class
```

That would be the straight VB fix to your current issue.  As what has been said, there are some other underlying issues you will want to address in the C code.  The biggest one being, data size validation.  And overall data integrity.  Remember, without a null char, identifying when and how strings end is a mystery, and that mystery can cause some REALLY weird reactions, but mostly just crashes.

Zero your chars before assigning them (and in some methodologies, it's a good idea to just put a null char at length-1 after you finish your data processing, just to be sure, this is handy if you are not working with fixed length operations).

Always initialize char buffers to one byte larger than you want, and fill that last char as null when you zero fill.

And lastly, if you know the character type, specify it.  Auto is nice, but specifics are better practice.

The combination of those events should remove all your errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any of the suggestions below will solve your problem, but there are things wrong (or strange) with your code.

```
void conv16to64(char s[], char b[])
```

First, what is the contract between the DLL and your VB application when it comes to strings?  How big must `s` and `b` be to ensure there isn't a memory overwrite?  Usually, DLL functions take another parameter, indicating the maximum number of characters to copy.

Second, if one of those parameters never changes what it points to, it should be `const`.  Going by your code, the function would be better off done this way:

```
void conv16to64(const char* s, char* b);
```

Third, arrays are indexed starting from `0` and go to `n-1` where `n` is the total number of entries in the array.  Your loops look suspicious, as they either start from 1, like here:

```
for (i=1; i<=64; i++)
    b[i] = t[i];
```

or they end at a value using `<=` as the terminating condition.  Whenever I see that, it more often than not is a mistake.  Like this:

```
for (i=0; i<=16; i++)
```

You are copying 17 characters, not 16 characters.  This could lead to an "off-by-1" memory overwrite error.

Foruth, in the comments, you were already told about the endless `else` chain.  A good programmer always looks for repeating patterns in their code, and attempts to fix them.  All you needed to do, for example, is multiply `j` by 4.

In your `case` statement, you could simply done something along these lines (and this isn't even sophisticated at all):

```
const char *binStrings[] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110",
                             "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101",
                             "1110", "1111"};
//...
const char *pBinString = 0;
if ( c[i] >= '0' && c[i] <= '9' )
    pBinString = binStrings[c[i] - '0'];
else
if ( c[i] >= 'A' && c[i] <= 'F' )
    pBinString = binStrings[c[i] -'A' + 10];       
if ( pBinString )
    memcpy(t+j, pBinString, 4);
```

In other words, just two `if()` statements testing the value of `c[i]` would be done, and given that value, it serves as an index into an array with the requisite character string.  The code above assumes that you are running on a computer that uses the ASCII collating sequence.  Again, not *the* most sophisticated way to do this, but it at least removes the redundancy.

But however, your issue is more than likely you're not providing strings that are large enough to this function, or this function erroneously overwrites memory due to the "off-by-1" errors that could occur.